# Xamarin forms load FontAwesome fonts from database (MySQL)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, xamarin.forms, font-awesome

I'm trying to add some scaling to a Universal App and part of this involves replacing some text with icons.

With the below code I am able to set the icon in the XAML.

```
<TextBlock Name="txtNote" Text="&#xf0f3;" FontFamily="FontAwesomePro"/>
```

And I'm also able to do the same from codebehind.

```
private void SetFont()
{
    txtNote.Text = "\uF0f3";
}
```

But here is the issue I'm having. I have a MySQL database with a "icon" column.
I have tried both "" and "\uF0f3" but my output for label is:

```
"&#xf0f3;"

"\uF0f3"
```

it doesnt convert to the icon.

This is how I'm setting my icon

```
private void SetCustomIconFromDB()
{
    string tempIcon = dataset.tables[0].Rows[0]["icon"].ToString();
    BindingContext = tempIcon;
}
```

Comment: 1.How do you save the icons into MySQL database? you may refer to [Font Awesome List in MySQL](https://gist.github.com/zulfu/3c56e6d95008c1b7c8cb). 2. Can you set the breakpoint at `string tempIcon` to check the data of it?

Comment: I have set a break point, and the data I'm getting out is "\uF0f3". So it's basicly the same. I'm gussing it has to do with encoding.

Comment: Yes, "\uF0f3" is unicoded and you also need set `FontFamily="FontAwesomePro"` for the icon.

Comment: Yes, FontFamily is set to FontAwesomePro. I now noticed that I'm actually getting "\\uF0f3" with two backslaches. I tried tempIcon.replace("\\u","\u"); but it still didnt work

Comment: Getting "\\uF0f3" would not work,you may need add `@` or `$`in front of the icon as a Conversion. What if you insert the icon into database as `&#xf0f3`? Could it be working?